# Teams "refresh" adaptive card returns 209 error in group chat

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Adaptive card "Refresh" action in Teams one to one chat doesn't work for companion
and for me after Teams cache clear but it works for any user in channel.

I'm posting an adaptive card with "refresh" action in Teams one to one chat from compose extension. "Refresh" action is triggered in compose box and I see result of refresh when push it out to the chat. "Refresh" action doesn't work for a user with whom I'm chatting, user sees [image: refresh action error]
If I open the chat in browser, "refresh" doesn't happen for me anymore, instead I see an initial card like on attached sreenshot for the card I just posted.
In browser's developer tools -> "network" I see 403 code for the request is done to *[https://amer.ng.msg.teams.microsoft.com/v1/agents/28:{bot_ad_app_registration_id}/invoke](https://amer.ng.msg.teams.microsoft.com/v1/agents/28:%7Bbot_ad_app_registration_id%7D/invoke)* with a responce

```
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "message": "Invoke validation failed. User forbidden to perform action",
    "standardizedError": {
        "errorCode": 209,
        "errorSubCode": 1,
        "errorDescription": "Invoke validation failed. User forbidden to perform action"
    }
}
```

My Teams compose extension is driven by Visual Studio through ngrok, in case of broken "refresh" described above request to ngrok doesn't happen.

Part of Teams App Extension Manifest:

```
 {
    "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "bot_id_is_here",
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "webView",
          "description": "description_is_here",
          "title": "title_is_here",
          "type": "action",
          "fetchTask": true,
          "context": [ "compose" ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "bot_id_is_here",
      "needsChannelSelector": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "groupchat"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity"
  ]
}
```

The solution perflectly works in channels: refresh happens both for me and all users, requests to the ngrok tunnel are routed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was because of missed bot. Bot isn't added to the "groupchat" automaticaly. Solved by adding a bot on the launch of messaging extension.

```
        protected override async Task<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync(
            ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext,
            MessagingExtensionAction action,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                // Check if your app is installed by fetching member information.
                var member = await TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.From.Id, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (ErrorResponseException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Body.Error.Code == "BotNotInConversationRoster")
                {
                    return await Task.FromResult(this.CardsFabric.GetAddMissedBotCard());
                }

                throw; // It's a different error.
            }

            return await Task.FromResult(this.CardsFabric.GetSearchDialog());
        }
```

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved. Thanks for informing.